# How to configure PuTTY to display these characters?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, putty

```
☢ ☍ ⌘ ✰ ⣿ ⚡ ☯ ⚑  ↺  ⤴  ⤵ blabla
```

I need to display symbols above in Windows 7 using proportional fonts. However, some symbols are not properly displayed. This particular example is using `Courier New`.

[image: damn it!]

I have English(US) set in my regional settings.

**Update:**

The ultimate goal is to show in PuTTY this

[image]

As you can see on the left side there are many special chars.

Now see what I get with `DejaVu Mono` font.

[image: DejaVu Mono]

This one with `Courier New`

[image: Courier New]

This one with `Consolas`

[image: Consolas]

This one with `Inconsolata`

[image: Inconsolata]

This is test output with `DejaVu Sans Mono`.

[image]
[Click here to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5A2Z.png)

Now compare those with the screenshot right below **Update**

Comment: Not all fonts support all symbols - are you looking for a proportional font with wide symbol support, or a way to get these characters in a particular font?

Comment: @dsolimano: Proportional font with wide symbol support, because I need to see those symbols in Putty. Moreover, it has to be Unicode font.

Comment: I think you mean *monospace* not *proportional* (Courier New is a monospace font).

Comment: Fixed width in other words )

Comment: I’m confused, why can’t you [just use `Courier New`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jlRz4.png) if it has the glyps you need?

Comment: @Synetech: plz see my update and thanks for editing title. I originally thought it's possible to simplify the question, but looks like it's more complex.

Comment: You only need to set the font in PuTTY, but the trick is finding a good font that has the glyphs you need. Where did you get the screenshot of Notepad? Did you make it yourself or find it on the Internet? Also, what is the app in the first screenshot (purple title bar)? Where did you get that screenshot?

Comment: @Synetech: it's my PC, where Putty also is running. Just copied the glympses to my notepad. The app is Pyroscope, which is rtorrent extension. It is terminal app. Screenshot from wiki http://code.google.com/p/pyroscope/wiki/ScreenShotGallery

Comment: You might want to try some of the fonts listed [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26a1/fontsupport.htm). They support the High Voltage symbol, which is one of the two `Courier New` appears to have trouble with. `Segoe UI Symbol` works, but it's not monospaced. Really, `DejaVu Sans Mono` *should* have worked (see WakiMiko's answer below). Oddly enough, [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2934/fontsupport.htm) lists those arrows your `DejaVu` screenshot is struggling with as existing in `DejaVu Serif`, not `DejaVu Sans`. They seem to work in `DejaVu Sans` for me.

Comment: Make sure putty is set to utf-8, if it isn't.

Comment: @Bob: `DejaVu Sans Mono` really doesn't work for me, could it mean there is something else in the system/Putty/shell env vars to tweak?

Comment: @Rob: it's set to UTF-8.

Comment: https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/putty-configuration/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Everson Mono](http://www.evertype.com/emono/) works in  PuTTY (a very important condition; many other fonts work, e.g. in konsole) for all the characters you posted. Doing a full test with the Python script, however, reveals a block that isn't quite right.

```
python -c 'print u"\u22c5 \u22c5\u22c5 \u201d \u2019 \u266f \u2622 \u260d \u2318 \u2730 " \
u"\u28ff \u26a1 \u262f \u2691 \u21ba \u2934 \u2935 \u2206 \u231a \u2240\u2207 \u2707 " \
u"\u26a0\xa0\u25d4 \u26a1\xa0\u21af \xbf \u2a02 \u2716 \u21e3 \u21e1  \u2801 \u2809 " \
u"\u280b \u281b \u281f \u283f \u287f \u28ff \u2639 \u2780 \u2781 \u2782 \u2783 \u2784 " \
u"\u2785 \u2786 \u2787 \u2788 \u2789 \u25b9\xa0\u254d \u25aa \u26af \u2692 \u25cc " \
u"\u21c5 \u21a1 \u219f \u229b \u267a ".encode("utf8")'
```

[image: Everson Mono on PuTTY to a virtual Kubuntu machine]

To use Everson Mono on PuTTY it may be necessary to tick the `Allow selection of variable-pitch fonts` box in `Window` -> `Appearance` -> `Font settings` section.

Other fonts, such as DejaVu Sans Mono, work perfectly in other programs, possibly borrowing glyphs from other files (I'm not sure how TT fonts work), which doesn't seem to work in PuTTY. Code2000 should have worked, but it did something... odd... to my PuTTY window. It may work for you. Every font I've tried works directly in konsole, even those that should not. It might be worth looking into an alternative client/emulator.

Comment: OK so far this one is closest, although some glyphses are very unclear even if I set font size to 16 and also cyrillic letters looks not proportional (one is bigger than another). But we are almost there. I would appreciate if someone can point to similar font which more looks like to `inconsolate` - clear and distinguishable even with small sizes. Thanks Bob, I will upvote your answer.

Comment: Anyway, I will accept your answer and repost another question with precise unicode font character ranges. I've tried all listed in Wiki, seems I need to find commercial one.

Answer (score 21):

What you need to do is to set the font (Figure 1) and encoding (Figure 2) in PuTTY.

The font in your screenshot is [*Inconsolata*](http://levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) (get the OTF file and copy it to your Windows Fonts folder). (PyroScope [suggests](http://code.google.com/p/pyroscope/wiki/RtorrentExtendedCanvas#Setting_up_your_terminal) [*DejaVu Sans Mono*](https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/) for Windows. Get `dejavu-fonts-ttf-2.33.zip`, extract the four `DejaVuSansMono*.ttf` files, and copy them to the Windows Fonts folder.)

The encoding to use is **UTF-8**.

**Figure 1:** Set the font:

[image: PuTTY font set to Deja Vu Sans Mono]

**Figure 2:** Set the encoding:

[image: PuTTY encoding set to UTF-8]

Comment: Which font exactly? I have tried both you mentioned, see my update.

Comment: with `Inconsalata` it's even more crippled, not even saying that Cyrillic chars are gone... see my update screenshot. Putty is set to UTF-8.

Comment: That's the problem... See my screenshot update.

Comment: Deja Vu **Mono Sans** + UTF-8 doesn’t work?

Comment: No it does not. Screenshot reflects python test output as per Pyroscope suggestion. Half of the symbols are crippled.

Comment: I'm using 'Oh My ZSH' and I tried both 'Everson Mono' and 'Deja Vu'. 'Deja Vu' seems to be the correct font for the default theme at least.

Comment: I started off with inconsolata(8-10), but the antialiasing is bugging the eyes, moving to dejavu sans mono 8, and this looks just like my arch linux box now too.  really crisp, a slight anti alias effect, that i still dont like it still apparent barely, but for the most part, this is the best font i have seen on putty.  (i prefer incolsolatas, but on putty it just doesnt cut it for me)

Comment: As I can see now DejaVu Sans Mono now comes built into PuTTY you no longer need to install it

Answer (score 16):

#### Update 2020

Suggest to install and use some patched fonts with basic emoji support, e.g., https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts

---

I checked the accepted solution, however, on my machine, putty doesn't show *Everson Mono* or *DejaVu Sans Mono* in its font list. (There must have been something wrong with my system configuration).

Besides, I don't like to change my favorite monospaced font.

After some Googling, I found a [more preferable solution](http://web.archive.org/web/20160516075653/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688134.aspx):

**Add (or Edit) an multi-string value for your preferred font under the Windows registry key**

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink

The added (or edited) key name should be the font name, and the value associated is a list of fallback font options to display the characters not recognized by previous font. There should be some existing ones, you can copy the value from there.

For me, I added an entry:

```
Monaco -> 
    msyh.ttf,Microsoft YaHei Regular
    SIMSUN.TTC,SimSun
    MINGLIU.TTC,PMingLiU
    MSGOTHIC.TTC,MS UI Gothic
    BATANG.TTC,Batang
```

Reboot and now Putty is able to show the Unicode characters correctly:

[image: oh-my-zsh prompt]

Comment: You have to "Allow selection of variable pitch fonts".  It doesn't recognize Everson Mono as monospace for some reason.  Still doesn't show the characters correctly for me with that font, though.

Comment: I had to reboot in order to get Windows 10 and PuTTY to display the fallback.  YMMV.

Comment: @AntoniusBloch Yes, a system reboot is required.

Answer (score 2):

[DejaVu Sans Mono](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page) works for me. Of course there are other fonts out there that will work just as well.

[image]

**EDIT:** If you are running rtorrent in `screen`, make sure to set screen to use utf8 too.

Comment: I've updated my original post. Still looking for proper font to display as close as possible what I see in screenshot.

Comment: Links is broken